# Arduino compile error: xxx does not name a type (despite it being declared 10 lines before)

Tags: c++, c, arduino

A link to the image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9I3R.png

An exempt from my code (bits omitted because they are of no importance)

```
struct viosReturnType {
  bool done;
  long long int returned;
  bool remapped;
};
viosReturnType viosButtonprompt(char buf1[16], char buf2[16], bool keysp[6] = {0}, String *strar = 0, int *statear = 0) {...}
viosReturnType viosRemapreturn(viosReturnType lreturner, int *indexedarray){...}
```

`viosButtonprompt` gave me 0 trouble and my program has been working correctly for a while now.
Adding the `viosRemapreturn` gives me

```
xxx/LVIOS.ino:585:1: error: 'viosReturnType' does not name a type
 viosReturnType viosRemapreturn(viosReturnType lreturner, int *indexedarray){
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

No other problems. Code inside functions has 0 effect on any of this. Arguments have 0 effect on any of this. Image shows that all of this isnt in any other function, its all declared globally and that its the same "viosReturnType". What is this, please help i beg you.
I tried putting the second function above the first, no effect, same error, on the same function, at a different line.

In addition: I now tried declaring an empty function, just copying the top line of my other function declaration.

```
viosReturnType viosRemapReturn(char buf1[16], char buf2[16], bool keysp[6] = {0}, String *strar = 0, int *statear = 0) {/*empty*/}
```

It works! Success! And then i removed the copied arguments.

```
viosReturnType viosReturnRemap(){/*still empty*/}
```

And it threw up the same error. My mind is exploding.

Reprex:

```
int SmartPoint() {}
struct viosReturnType {
  bool done;
  long long int returned;
  bool remapped;
};
viosReturnType returner;
viosReturnType viosRemapReturn(viosReturnType lreturner, int *indexedarray) {
  if (lreturner.done)
    return {1, indexedarray[lreturner.returned], 1};
}
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

You see that "SmartPoint"? Yeah, if i remove it, this reprex compiles. But i cant really remove it anywhere in my real file, i dont have any empty functions like that or anything!

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile *as is* that exactly demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Is this C++ or C?

Comment: @dbush did that.

Comment: @JohnFilleau its the whatever weird mix of c/c++ that arduino uses. Assume its c++.

Comment: Your MCVE ... [isn't](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d2ca5bac103c42a). Aside from warnings about missing return statements, the snippet compiles just fine, as standard C++ anyway.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings notice that this Is arduino code. Both the default and the pro arduino ide's fail to compile this. Checked now, even the online arduino compiler - https://create.arduino.cc/editor/pepfof/b2d0edc4-460a-4bc4-9fb1-4d523ce5dc24/preview

Comment: I'll bet the actual code says `viosRetrunType`. That's my favorite typo...

Comment: My initial joojling indicates that in order for a function in Arduino to return a `struct` (or any custom datatype), that `struct` needs to be defined in its own `.h` file? Or maybe the function that returns the `struct` needs to be defined in its own `.h` file? Not sure why yet. I'm not an arduino guy.

Comment: @PeteBecker It doesnt. Refer to image.
@JohnFilleau I mean, the other functions compile just fine and even this one does... When you remove that first function. Weird stuff, right? Im pulling my hair out, but sure thing i Will try defining it in an `.h` file.

Comment: Apparently arduino will auto-generate function declarations ABOVE everything else in your code if those functions accept or return a datatype larger than 2 words. I have no idea why this is done. You can hit <SHIFT> when you click the compile button to see what the autogenerated code looks like according to this forum post https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=166365.0

Comment: @JohnFilleau Jesus that worked. Thanks. Answer the question so i can mark your answer as correct. Thank you. (i mean the separate `.h` file). It Still Is very weird that the other functions did compile though, they indeed are larger than this godforsaken one ive been trying to implement...

Comment: What exactly worked? Putting the struct in the `.h` file or putting the functions in the `.h` file?

Comment: It looks like just declaring the prototype directly above the function definition itself should suppress the automatic prototype construction, which I think looks a little cleaner.

Comment: @JohnFilleau yeah the first thing. Nevermind now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arduino for some reason thinks it's a good idea to auto-generate function prototypes if you define a function that takes a custom datatype. I assume they do this for "ease of use" so you don't have to worry about forward declarations? This causes problems (as you have observed) when that function uses a custom datatype. Then that prototype is placed before the custom datatype definition, which confuses the compiler.

To overcome this automatic prototype creation, you need to explicitly declare the function prototype *after* the declaration of your datatype. Like this

```
int SmartPoint() {}
struct viosReturnType {
  bool done;
  long long int returned;
  bool remapped;
};
viosReturnType returner;
// this prototype is to suppress arduino automatic prototype construction
// above viosReturnType definition
viosReturnType viosRemapReturn(viosReturnType lreturner, int *indexedarray);
viosReturnType viosRemapReturn(viosReturnType lreturner, int *indexedarray) {
  if (lreturner.done)
    return {1, indexedarray[lreturner.returned], 1};
}
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

Another solution is to place the struct definition in a separate `.h` file, and include it in your main file, so that the prototypes are included after the inclusion.

```
// vios_return_type.h
#ifndef VIOS_RETURN_TYPE_H
#define VIOS_RETURN_TYPE_H
struct viosReturnType {
  bool done;
  long long int returned;
  bool remapped;
};
#endif // VIOS_RETURN_TYPE_H
```

```
#include "vios_return_type.h"

int SmartPoint() {}
viosReturnType returner;

viosReturnType viosRemapReturn(viosReturnType lreturner, int *indexedarray) {
  if (lreturner.done)
    return {1, indexedarray[lreturner.returned], 1};
}
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

Comment: Or declare the struct in a `.h`. Otherwise correct, thanks!

Comment: Code compiles ok, to the OP get rid of the warnings about missing returns, they can pile up to error with ArduinoIDE compiler exiting without a real helpful message.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings as I'm not an Arduino person, I had no idea they did this. It sounds maddening.

Comment: That's why it's a great answer - deduction skills on fleek :)

Comment: @Codebreaker007 dont worry, not a thing in the real code